# MVC - Redirect to another view by click on image with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-helper

I am using MVC.

I have this line in my html:

```
<div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="../../Content/img/logo3.png" alt="" /></a></div
```

But I want to redirect to another view when a user click on the logo.

How can I do that? I need the same structure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give your anchor an `href` value pointing to the controller action that you want to redirect to:

```
<div id="logo">
    <a href="@Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller")">
        <img src="../../Content/img/logo3.png" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<%: Url.Content("~/Controllor/View") %>">
                <div id="logo">
                </div>
 </a>
```